# Remove DEM data in a specific region

Tags: raster, gdal, dem

I am trying to extract current USGS DEM data that corresponds to [an old USGS map](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/ht-bin/tv_browse.pl?id=82851d286900598a02f3193f75affd60). I have downloaded the DEM covering the corresponding area, and am now trying to extract the correct subset. The area covered in the old map is irregularly shaped. I have successfully extracted a rectangular area using GDAL, however this includes extra data not present in the original map.

My understanding is that GDAL translate only accepts rectangles as bounding boxes.

Is there a way to set all the values in the unneeded region either to a no-data value or to 0?

Here is a picture illustrating the issue:
[image: region to be clipped]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a polygon named `delete` for the region you want to delete from the raster (unneeded region, in orange on the screenshot below).
2. Create a polygon `extent` (red outline polygon) that covers the extent of your raster using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Create layer from extent` and set the raster as input.
3. Cut out shape of `delete` from the polygon `extent` using `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Difference` and set `extent` as `input` and `delete` as `Overlay layer`. You get a polygon `difference` (blue) that corresponds to the regions of your raster you want to keep.
4. Go to `Menu Raster / Extraction / Clip raster by mask layer`, set your raster as input and the polygon `difference` (from step 3) as `mask layer`. Don't forget to fill in `Assign a specified nodata value to output bands`. Run the tool and you get what you want:

[image]

And this is the output you get:

[image]