# How to give a value of 0 in a raster only in a certain area?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon

I want to give the value of 0 in this raster but only in the area within the polygon. So the final outcome is the same raster file but with 0 values in that area

How can I do that?

[image: Raster with the area that has to be 0]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing raster cell values within a polygon using QGIS GUI?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84563/changing-raster-cell-values-within-a-polygon-using-qgis-gui)

Comment: See this question here, it's almost the same question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384549/remove-dem-data-in-a-specific-region - in the answer, at step 4, `Assign a specified nodata value to output bands`, insert your value 0 to get the result you want.

Comment: I would use https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157047/erase-shapefile-polygon-area-from-geotiff/157055#157055.