# Restricting viewshed to less than 360 degrees?

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I'm using QGIS with the visibility analysis plugin.

I want to do a viewshed in only one direction. Is it possible to restrict the analysis rather than doing a 360 degree analysis?

Comment: Would it be OK to analyze the full 360 degrees and mask out from the result everything that is outside your sector of interest?

Answer (score 1):

You can crop the raster DEM layer using a polygon to keep only that part of the DEM where you want to have the viewshed applied. In this way, the calculation should be faster as no "waste" viewshed has to be calculated.

1. Create a polygon layer that covers all the areas of the DEM that you want to delete - tus only those parts of the DEM that you want to keep for the viewshed should remain uncoverd.
2. Use `Menu Raster / Extraction / Clip raster by mask layer` to clip the pixels where your polygon lies.

See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384557/88814